# Wrong sign conversion when converting IPv4 address to std::array of bytes

Tags: c++, type-conversion, compiler-warnings

I am confused about the following compiler warning that I get when trying to convert the ipv4 address `in_addr` from `struct sockaddr_in` which is a `uint32_t` to a std::array of bytes.

```
std::array<uint8_t, 4> IpAddress;
struct in_addr in_addr = {};
const char* addr_str = "168.212.226.204";

if (inet_pton(AF_INET, addr_str, &in_addr))
{
    uint8_t* addr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&(in_addr.s_addr));

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        IpAddress[i] = addr[i]; // warning: conversion to 'std::array<unsigned char, 4>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}' from 'int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude try with `-Wsign-conversion`

Comment: To the OP: For future questions please include how you build your program (and if possible a proper [mcve]), and show us the exact options you use as well as the full and complete output from the shown example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is here:

```
IpAddress[i] = addr[i];
         ^^^
```

Since `i` is an `int`, but the operator `[]` of `std::array` accepts `size_type`, you get a warning.

You can fix this by simply changing `i` to be `size_t` instead of `int`:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning seems to be on the array index itself, `i`, the loop counter. Array indexes are unsigned types. Look closely at the actual error message:

> warning: conversion to 'std::array<unsigned char, 4>::size_type

Guess what `size_type` means?

Comment: Don't think the snark is needed. Could you replace the final paragraph with a useful hint or some information that helps the OP?